# How to get index of the first digit in String

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find out how to get the index of the first digit in String. I have an idea how to do that using some loops but it would be really ugly so I would prefer some regex. Could someone give me a clue how to do that using regex?

Comment: "have an idea how to do that using some loops but it would be really ugly so I would prefer some regex. Could someone give me a clue how to do that using regex??"

Funny, I think "some loops" is more readable then regex....

Comment: Ok, I should have rather said efficient and shorter than "ugly" but anyway do not tell me that loops with several if statements are better than one line of a regex expression...

Comment: That very much depends on the regex, however this one is so simple any other way just seems silly.

Comment: @Husky the for loop is readable by anyone and fastest than all regex submitted as answer. [Check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557633/1248177)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
firstDigit = 'Testi2ng4'.match(/\d/) // will give you the first digit in the string
indexed = 'Test2ing4'.indexOf(firstDigit)
```

Well I guess I need to look at my methods more closely, you can just do `'Testin323g'.search(/\d/)`;

Comment: yeah I kinda realized he never said he didn't want 0.

Comment: I hope you did not pick that match/indexOf solution since it is the slowest out of the bunch.

Comment: Arguably your first answer is the slowest because it doesn't work, so it will never reach a solution. However you are right string.search is pretty fast.

Comment: Since we are talking about speed, what about a benchmark: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557633/1248177

Answer (score 20):

**Search:** [Fastest way]

```
var str = "asdf1";
var search = str.search(/\d/)
console.log(search);
```

**Match:** [Slower than a for loop, just showing another way of doing it]

```
var str = "asdf1";
var match = str.match(/(\D+)?\d/)
var index = match ? match[0].length-1 : -1;
console.log(index);
```

Comment: I find it amusing that you're pointing out that mine is the slowest when your first solution is 74% slower than doing a search (mine is 85% slower). It's like two men arguing about which turtle is faster in a horse race.

Comment: If you want answers to be looked at critically maybe you should review your own, your first answer gives me NaN on chrome. Your second answer yields undefined, because str.search returns an integer not an object.

Comment: Since we are talking about speed, what about a benchmark: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557633/1248177

Answer (score 12):

A for loop is fastest than a regex based solution:

```
function indexOfFirstDigit(input) {
  let i = 0;
  for (; input[i] < '0' || input[i] > '9'; i++);
  return i == input.length ? -1 : i;
}

function indexOfNaN(input) {
  let i = 0;
  for (; input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9'; i++);
  return i == input.length ? -1 : i;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBDoIwDEDvfEVPDEIkoF4U0YvxiB9gPAzYsIZsZAxjon47Ah5EEwzx2Pa1fe2ZXmiZKCz0RMiU1TWvRKJRCkCRsuueRzSyUBSVtuFmAORMA0IIXtAEXCqwAujKBzzCOgTiETDNd2rVpBakYRzHblsU05US7YjwBbk5E5k@wQYmPiwBA@NhGN8SO1Sl3mKGerTLqlO533t2/5gkUpQyZ24uM6v3EUL9eErsZtAQ4E9n8yGgdw6hcZKO4n4s/ODKlPstWNdP)

jsbench (higher is better):

```
TestCase results for your browser Firefox version 54.0
Test name               Benchmark results
indexOfFirstDigit        11,175,400 (±2.77)
regex search             3,787,617 (±5.22) (epascarello)
regex match              2,157,958 (±6.49) (epascarello)
regex match + indexOf    1,131,094 (±4.63) (VoronoiPotato)
```

I ran again some quick tests. Still fastest:

[image: chart of the race]

[Run it yourself!](http://jsben.ch/EwRKc)

Answer (score 4):

Use [string.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) to find the index with the regex `\d`

Answer (score 1):

If you were just looking for a one liner you could also try a functional programming approach and could do something like the following:

```
let myStr = "ID12345";
let myStrIndex = myStr.indexOf(myStr.split('').filter(x => !isNaN(parseInt(x, 10)))[0]);
```

The string is split into an array of characters and the filter function reduces that array to just the number characters. The first character of the new array is the first number character in the string so using indexOf on that character gives you the index you are looking for.

Of course if there is no number character in the string you will get an index of -1 as a result. And you could also use a different check if char is number function as the parameter to .filter() - I am sure there is something faster if that's a concern

Comment: This is overly complex and even costly for not so much. I am all for one-liner and functional programming, but this is not what programming is about. You should strieve for simplicity, readibility and performance. This is still a valid answer.